# Question about "looking out ahead" & "keep eyes ahead"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> The other thing is our hand position when we’re driving. It’s nice, soft hands are very important in learning to drive. We don’t want a death grip on that wheel. We want nice, soft hands, like pretty much anything that you do in sports, your hands have to be nice and soft. If your hands are soft and you’re not real tense, you’ll find that you have the ability to steer a car much, much better.
>
> You also want to be able to get the big picture when we’re driving. We don’t want to stare at anything because when you drive, you will follow your eyes. Okay? So if you’re looking to the right or you’re looking to the left and you’re staring at that portion of the vehicle, that’s the way the vehicle will move. When people drive a car for the first time, they have a difficult ability to understand how far they are away from the vehicle to the right, and that’s because the right side of the vehicle is a little further away from you than the left. So invariably what they usually do is they stare down to the right side, and what happens when you stare to the right, your car will go to the right. So you want to pick your eyes up. **You want to keep your eyes ahead of you looking out ahead** and you’ll find that you follow your eyes. So if your eyes are straight ahead the car will have a better chance of going straight.

1. What does it mean saying ** keep your eyes ahead of you** ?
2. What is the difference between **look ahead** and as written in the passage **look out ahead** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Keep your eyes looking straight through the windshield at the road in front of you. But not staring. Quick glances around you for the "big picture" (see my other answer) but mostly you keep your eyes on the road directly in front of you.
2. In this context, there's no difference. It means the same thing.

Note: there are a few grammar errors in this document. It is not written in perfect English, so don't feel bad if you're having trouble with it, and don't try to learn any grammar from it. :)

Comment: I don't know where this passage came from. It does read more like a transcript of a narration, rather than an written manual.